# I want to know the authenticity of these hadiths

Tags: hadith, authenticity, uloom-al-hadith

"He who has committed [haad], let him cover himself with the covering of God, and let him repent to God. For on him who reveals to us his deed in the open, we will enforce the Book of God." (Al-Hakim, Mustadrak, 4:244, 383, Source in Arabic [here](http://islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=74&bookhad=7523))

Narrated 'Aishah:
that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ): "Avert the legal penalties from the Muslims as much as possible, if he has a way out then leave him to his way, for if the Imam makes a mistake in forgiving it would be better than making mistake in punishment." ([Jami' At-Tirmidhi no. 1424](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/17/2))

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. It would be helpful if you added the Arabic original or a link to your posted ahadith. I couldn't so far find the hadith from al-Mustadrak

Answer (score 2):

Both ahadith actually contain reliable and useful information.
As for the first it gives a guideline for a person who committed a sin that is subject of hadd: It says that we shouldn't reveal that we have committed a sin that is subject of had (punishment) as this is a kind of publicising and we are taught:

> All the people of my Ummah would get pardon for their sins except those who publicise them. And (it means) that a servant should do a deed during the night and tell the people in the morning that he has done so and so, whereas Allah has concealed it. And he does a deed during the day and when it is night he tells the people, whereas Allah has concealed it. Zuhair has used the word hijar for publicising. (See for example in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/55/68))

This doesn't mean we should lie if asked by a judge! Note that sincere repentance might lead to lifting a hadd!

While the second hadith shows an important rule for the people (judges) who may need to give a verdict of hadd: They shouldn't apply hadd if there's any doubt.

Both ahadith -regardless of their own authenticity- have many backups in the Qur'an and sunnah. But as you required a statement on the authenticity of these specific narrations you may find it in the following:

- The hadith from al-Mustadrak ([Source](http://islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=74&bookhad=7523) in Arabic) can be found in al-Muwatta' (see [here](https://sunnah.com/urn/515130)), az-Zorqani in his commentary of al-Muwatta' said that it has also been compiled by al-Bayhaqi in his as-Sunan al-Kubra -see [here](http://islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?bk_no=71&ID=3673&idfrom=17017&idto=17141&bookid=71&startno=27) in Arabic- and considerd as sahih by ibn as-Sakkan ابن السكن and others among them as-Suyuti -see [here](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=3217&idto=3220&bk_no=77&ID=616) in Arabic-. Al-Albani has also considered is a sahih -according to this fatwa on islamqa #[240409](https://islamqa.info/ar/240409)- or hassan -according to this Arabic fatwa on islamweb #[49568](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=49568)-.
- The hadith from [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/17/2) has also been compiled by other authors such as al-Hakim in his al-Mustadrak the major issue in this hadith is already quoted by at-Tirmidhi himself the narrator Yazid ibn Ziyad a-Dimashqi يزيد بن زياد is da'if imam al-Bukhari even said his hadith is rejected (munkar) and an-Nasa'i considerd him as rejected so this is the main reason while scholars such al-Bayhaqi, al-Bagahwi, ibn Hajar al-'Asqalani and others have considerd it as da'if. See also fatwa islamweb #[366895](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/366895) in Arabic.